# How to Debug where microcontroller is stuck?

Tags: c, debugging, microcontroller, atmel

I am working on a board based on atsame70q20, I have implemented a very minimal SNMP library and I am using it to query for certain OIDs from some controllers. The problem is after a while it gets stuck while querying the OID and reboots due to watchdog timer expires. We are using FreeRTOS 7.3.0 and LWIP 2.1.0. I don't have an idea how to figure out where it is getting stuck. I put debug statements to find the exact location and even the debug string is just printing partially. I just wanted some pointers on how to figure out where the flow was going.

```
    lwip_sendto(lSocket,(const void *)arr,arr_len,MSG_DONTWAIT,&serverAddr,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));



debug_puts("Stuck Here2\r\n");
memset(gv_snmpRespData,0, 512);
fd.fd = lSocket; // socket handler
fd.events = POLLIN;
wdt_restart(WDT);
debug_puts("Stuck Here3\r\n");
ret = poll(&fd, 1, 500); // 500 millisecond for timeout
switch (ret) {
    case -1:
    // Error
    nBytes = -1;
    break;
    case 0:
    // Timeout
    nBytes = -1;
    break;
    default:
    nBytes = lwip_recvfrom(lSocket,gv_snmpRespData,512,MSG_WAITALL,NULL,NULL);
    break;
}

*pdu_arr_len = nBytes;

lwip_close(lSocket);

if(nBytes > 0)
    return 0;

return 1;
```

I gets stuck on statement Stuck Here3 and reboots.

Comment: The obvious question then is, how long is your watchdog timeout?

Comment: I imagine the timeout will be about the time it takes for the serial output of however much of ”Stuck Here3\r\n” is output. Is lwip_recvfrom blocking if it doesn’t get data? Is the timeout longer than 500ms for the poll?

Comment: @Lundin The WDT is 15 secs. Its not he watchdog that is at fault here because I have tried with watchdog disabled also and it never comes out once it is stuck.

Comment: @barny Yes lwip_recvfrom  is blocking and I didn;t understand what you were asking in "Is the timeout longer than 500ms for the poll?". For the poll timeout is 500ms.

Comment: I meant the wdt timeout and that's fine at 15s for a 500ms poll. So if lwip_recvfrom doesn't get data, i.e. it blocks, what happens next?

Comment: @barny it reaches lwip_recvfrom only if there is some data arrived at the socket otherwise it skip it and returns. I've added rest of the code after lwip_recvfrom. And anyway when it gets stuck it doesn't even reach the poll. It hangs at the debug statement before that. Also one thing to note is that if I add some more statements before "Stuck Here3", it doesn't reach till there and gets stuck even before the "stuck here3".

Comment: I would turn the watchdog off to not mask the other problem.  A debugger can show you at what point it "hangs".  My guesses are 1. stack overflow (!) 2. deadlock.

Comment: @tonypdmtr I've already tried with watchdog disabled. Its just stays there indefinitely. Can you please explain how can I use debugger for it because putting a break point is not feasible as it doesn't hang every time takes about 1-2 hours and that piece executes almost 20 times per minute so it would be painstaking to skip it each time manually until it hangs. Is there any other way besides breakpoint?

Comment: @oddparity Most debuggers can interrupt while free running.  So, let it run until it "hangs" and when it does, stop the debugger (at any random instruction obviously) and single step from there to see what causes the 'infinite' condition.

Comment: @tonypdmtr OK thanks I'll try that